# Gitlab-ci: if MR exist just trigger merge_request detach pipeline, if not trigger source branch pipeline. Those 2 pipelines shouldn't run in same time

Tags: gitlab, sonarqube, gitlab-ci

I want to see sonar results in the MR(merge request) command section when I create a MR.

My main expectations:

- if there is an existing MR for the source branch, trigger detached pipeline (do not trigger feature pipeline. I need only that one for reviewing sonar results in MR commands)
- if there isn't an existing MR for the source branch, just trigger the normal feature(source) branch pipeline

I tried to do it with the below example stage. But when I pushed the commit to the source pipeline, while MR is exist for source branch. I still getting double pipeline. Detach and source pipelines are running and I don't want to see both in same time, plus except not working with rules configuration. How can I integrate except section with rules part.

This is my gitlab-ci stage:

```
deploy:
  stage: deployment
  when: manual
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CUSTOM_VARIABLE == "true" || $CUSTOM_VARIABLE == "true"'
  script:
    - ....
    - ....
  except:
    - tags
    - main
```

I also tried below rules, if one of them fit my condition don't run the other one. But it still trigger both pipelines.

```
deploy:
  stage: deployment
  when: manual
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CUSTOM_VARIABLE == "true"'
      when: on_success
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CUSTOM_VARIABLE == "true"'
      when: on_success
  script:
    - ....
    - ....
  except:
    - tags
    - main
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Covered in [`workflow:rules` templates](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#workflowrules-templates), In this case, you can use the [`CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS` variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) to determine whether to run the pipeline for merge request or just the feature branch.

> If you use both [pipelines for merge requests and branch pipelines], duplicate pipelines might run at the same time. To prevent duplicate pipelines, use the CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS variable.

Using `workflow:rules` you can do this for the entire pipeline, but the same principle can also be applied to individual jobs.

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
```

This means your pipeline will run:

- for merge requests
- for branch pipelines UNLESS there is an open merge requests

Comment: it works thank you for the answer. I have one more quick question.  Before this workflow, I had `only: variables: [ $sample == "one" ]` condition in each my stages. Right now I can't use this with workflow, isn't it? The sample variable has to be equal to one otherwise don't run. How can I also apply this condition to workflow rules?

Comment: @hammer89 you could apply another rule -- if you require that variable to be present, add the condition with `&&` to the first and last `- if` rules. like `if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $sample == "one"'` -- If you want the pipeline to run _additionally_ when that variable is present (that is, irrespective of the other rules), you can just add `- if: '$sample == "one"'` as another rule

Comment: thank you again. What about if I want to use `except: -tags` in my stages.  As I know only and except can't work with rules methord. How can I use to avoid it? Here is also my another question for this . [my another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69825558/gitlab-ci-run-ci-job-with-rules-but-use-a-definition-to-avoid-ci-run-for-tags)

Comment: And also don't forget to add `- if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'` if you want tag pipelines to get triggered.

Comment: @sytech, With the above workflow rules, how to avoid the job not to run on Main branch? After a MR from branch to Main. Still that job get executed.?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
rules:
  - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
  - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS == 'false'
```

This means your pipeline will run:

- for merge requests
- for branch pipelines when there is no opened merge request