# Gitlab-ci: Run CI job with rules, but use a definition to avoid CI run for tags

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm using rule method in my stage. But with rule method, I don't want to trigger CI run for tags.
I need to find a way to avoid tags like `except: - tags`. Unfortunately except not working with rules. In shortly how can I avoid it?

I use this snippet in my stage but it did not work, it still triggers the pipeline after the creation of the tag.

```
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'
      when: never
```

This is my main deployment stage:

```
deploy:
  stage: deployment
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $sample == "one"'
      when: manual
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $sample == "one"'
      when: manual
  script:
    - ...
    - ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem. Just I added `- when: never` at the end of the rules. As a separate rule, it will block all different trigger cases.

```
deploy:
  stage: deployment
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $sync == "one"'
      when: manual
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $CI_OPEN_MERGE_REQUESTS'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_TAG'
      when: never
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH && $sync == "false"'
      when: manual
    - when: never
  script:
    - ...
    - ...
```