# Why is gitlab run duplicate pipelines on commit?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I have the following content of the `.gitlab-ci.yml` job:

```
stages:
  - stage1
  - stage2


job1:
  stage: stage1
  script:
    - echo "Running default stage1, pipeline_source=$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE"

job2:
  stage: stage2
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"
    - when: always
  script:
    - echo "Running STAGE2!   pipeline_source=$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE"
```

when I commit this change to a merge-request branch, it seems two pipelines are being started.

Is this a known issue in gitlab? Or do I understand something wrong here?

Answer (score 18):

GitLab creates pipelines both for your branch and for the merge request. This is an "expected"<sup>[1]</sup> feature of GitLab as a consequence of using `rules:`. (oddly enough, when using `only`/`except`, [merge request pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html#configure-pipelines-for-merge-requests) will only happen when using `only: - merge_requests`).

If you simply want to disable the 'pipelines for merge requests' and only run branch pipelines, you can include the default branch pipelines template, which provides a `workflow:` that prevents pipelines for merge requests.

```yaml
include:
  - template: 'Workflows/Branch-Pipelines.gitlab-ci.yml'
```

Additionally, you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69819558/5747944) for a workflow that will prevent duplicates between the pipelines for merge requests and branch pipelines *only* when a merge request is open.

---

[1]: I've always found this to be a quirk of GitLab and, as an administrator of GitLab for hundreds of users, I've gotten this question many many times. So, you're not alone in being surprised by this 'expected feature'

Comment: Not always two pipelines are started

Comment: Yeah, it depends. It's because of the use of `rules:` when a merge request is open. If a pipeline has no jobs with `rules` that catch on merge request pipelines, there will be just the branch pipeline. Another case might be for tag pipelines; a separate pipeline is created for tags as well.

Comment: That does not make any sense

Comment: @Alex sorry, perhaps I misunderstood your problem. Could you elaborate on what behavior is not expected?

Comment: The include template suggested didn't do any difference in my case. I still get both the branch and the MR context pipelines triggered.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't do anything wrong. This is actually intended, though it's a weird side-effect of the fact that Merge Requests have their own pipeline contexts. So when you commit to a branch that's associated with a merge request, two pipelines start:

1. A branch-based pipeline, with no context of the merge request
2. A merge request pipeline, with all the merge request variables populated (this is called a "detached" pipeline)

You can control this behavior by using a `workflow` keyword in your pipeline. We use the following workflow settings on our repositories:

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "schedule"
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_PROTECTED == "true"
```

The above rules will prevent the branch pipelines from running unless the branch is a protected branch (I.e., you're merging into the `main` branch), a tagged commit (I.e., you're releasing code), or the pipeline has been scheduled. This means that when you commit to a MR, the branch-based pipeline (#1 from the above numbers) doesn't run, and you are left with one pipeline running.

Comment: Not always two pipeline start.

Comment: My answer and sytech answers are essentially the same, and my response would be the same as the one he noted below :)

Comment: No, that suggested solution does not work. I am not able to start the pipeline in the branch.

Comment: If you use the solution I posted, you're correct, you wouldn't be able to start a branch-only pipeline because it's restricted to either a protected branch (`main` or your equivalent) or a branch that has an MR on it. That means you can't click on "CI/CD > Run Pipeline > (branch) > Run Pipeline", because that branch has no MR associate with it. If you want to manually start a pipeline that's associated to a MR, navigate to that MR, click on "Pipelines > Run Pipeline" at the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I temporarily disabled both the branch and the MR pipelines with these rules:

```
  workflow:
    rules:
      # Don't trigger any pipelines automatically whenever the feature branch or the MR context is concerned.
      - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME =~ /^feature\//'
        when: manual
      - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
        when: manual
      - when: always
```

You can obviously adjust them ad libidum.